# Connection' object has no attribute 'execute' pymysql

Tags: python, database-connection, pymysql, execute

Every time I try to create an account I get this error message:
***Connection' object has no attribute 'execute'***
Thank you for helping me.

I am working on an absence management form.
I am in the account creation phase.
I have set up a MySQL database in order to be able to save the connection information in it.

I attach a part of my code and the libraries:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import os


                con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",port=3306, user="root", password="",  database="database")
                cur=  con.cursor()
                con.execute("select * from compte where var=%s", self.var.get())
                row = cur.fetchone()
            
                con.comit()
                con.close
```

Comment: You want `cur.execute()`, not `con.execute()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `cur.execute()` not `con.execute()`.
**Note:** Apart from that you have a couple of typos on `commit()` and `close()`, See [Ref](https://zetcode.com/python/pymysql/)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox
from tkcalendar import *
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors
import os


con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",port=3306, user="root", password="",  database="database")
cur= con.cursor()
cur.execute("select * from compte where var=%s", self.var.get())
row = cur.fetchone()   
con.commit()
con.close()
```